# npm: How to install all dependencies from package.json globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install all dependencies inside `package.json` for a project using:

```
npm install -g
```

The installation is done in the project folder. Now, how do I install **all** dependencies **globally**?

Do I have to `npm install <package_name> -g` for every package or there is a command that will install them automatically?

Comment: I don't think a command to do this exists, and I don't see this as a common goal. I would make a script to do this more easily.

Comment: We all know that npm packages can include a very extensive number of files. I'm trying to avoid installing packages locally because those modules can get outdated easily, then I end up having loads of versions of the same module across various projects in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a list of packages to npm install `npm install <package_name> <package_name> -g` for example, `npm install package1 package2 -g`